# Modify menus shown to Portal users Odoo/Openerp

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

What I want to do is this:

When a new user is given access to the Portal, I want her only to be able to see a single Sales menu with a submenu Sales/Customers and nothing else.

I was able to do that by adding the menu to the Portal group, but I need to hide the other menus (Website,Mail,Projects). I removed all the other views from Portal group and made sure that my customer does not belong to any other group than Portal but the menus are still there.

From what I can understand the menus are shown only to certain groups of users. My user only belongs to the Portal group these menus are not referenced there. I only have my Sales/Customer there

How can I remove them?

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Comment: @Odedra this security problem, not sure for why you asking for code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out-of-box odoo is designed to show all those menu as portal menu, so what you want todo here is create new group with portal check-box true and assigned all menu you wnat him to see and assign needed security. Designing this group be bit lazy as you will have todo lot of trails.

Bests